# How to insert records from 2 tables without the primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, primary-key

How to insert records from 2 tables without the primary key in MySQL?

I would like to insert `table_a` with below sql:

```
insert into table_a select 
tc.id, tc.code,tb.name,tb.sordid,tb.others
from table_b tb 
left join table_c tc
on sb.code = spir.code
```

but above SQL will get the error of primary key error(table_c.id  = table_a.id are primary key ), I only can use below SQL

```
insert into table_a select 
tc.id, tc.code,tb.name,tb.sordid,tb.others
from table_b tb 
left join table_c tc
on sb.code = spir.code where tc.id is not null
```

table_a

```
id   code  name     sortid  others
-----------------------------------
1     abc  ASDAG     1      sfgsdf
1     abc   asgasd    2      asd
1     abc  asdgasd  3      sfgsdf
1     abc   asdgas    4      asd
2     ad  ASDAG     1      sfgsdf
2     ad   sd       2       asd
2     ad  sss       3     sfgsdf
3     adcs  ASDAG     1      sfgsdf
3     adcs   sd       2       asd
```

table_b

```
id   code  name     sortid  others
-----------------------------------
99     abc   asgasd    1      asd
99     abc  asdgasd    2      sfgsdf
6      ad  ASDAG       1      sfgsdf
```

table_c

```
id   code
----------
 1    abc
 2    ad
 3   adcs
```

but that's not what I need, if you need some sample data, please feel free to tell me, thanks so much for any advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and at least explain what the primary key is in `table_a`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi, I already updated my quesiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL offers two methods to avoid inserting rows in this case:

```
insert into table_a
    select tc.id, tc.code,tc.name,tb.sordid,tb.others
    from table_b tb left join
         table_c tc
         on sb.code = spir.code
    where tc.id is not null
    on duplicate key update id = values(id);
```

Note:  This avoids the error by not inserting the row.  I'm not sure if that is what you really want.

You can also use `insert ignore`.

Comment: hi,  I already updated my question, thanks so much for your answer

Comment: Hi, if I use your code, the existed records can't be updated

Comment: can I use `relace into` ?

Comment: @Fire . . . Of course the existing records can be updated.  That is what `on duplicate key` **does**.  I just didn't update any columns because it wasn't clear in your question what should be done.

Comment: hi, I am sorry for troubling you again, you mean your SQL didn't update any columns, right? I need to update existing records  and insert new records

Comment: @FIRE . . . This is how MySQL implements an upsert operation -- an operation that both inserts and updates rows.  You have to specify what you want updated, and your question doesn't have that information.

Comment: insert not existing records and update all existing records if changed

Comment: @FIRE. . . That is exactly what `on duplicate key` does.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `table_a` column doesn't allow nulls in the `id` field, so there is no way to insert the null values there.

You need to do either:

1. Allow nulls for `table_a.id`
2. Add some translation to your insert to end up with non-null values for the `id` field being inserted.